# nasty cookies from data1.mein-bmi.com

Tags: windows, google-chrome, cookies

Whenever I visit a website, it shows me that I have cookies from data1.mein-bmi.com. I wonder how I can trace the reason for this.

Example to reproduce:

1. I use Chrome on Windows to visit a web site, e.g. [www.superuser.com](http://www.superuser.com)
2. I click on the "lock" icon saying "view site information" -> Cookies -> allowed
3. I find a cookie from data1.mein-bmi.com. "Name" is plugin-key, "Content" is an arbitrary string, "Domain" is data1.mein-bmi.com, "Path" is /.

I could not find a web site where this is not happening for me. In order to find the reason, I went to menu -> more tools -> developer tools -> console.
It says:

```
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://pgjjikdiikihdfpoppgaidccahalehjh/webspeed.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://fheoggkfdfchfphceeifdbepaooicaho/sourceMap/chrome/scripts/iframe_form_detection.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://fheoggkfdfchfphceeifdbepaooicaho/sourceMap/chrome/scripts/iframe_form_detection.map: HTTP error: status code 404, 
net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
VM270:1 GET https://data1.mein-bmi.com/scripts/js?k=5b8acdca82df1a4e078b4567&s=c3VwZXJ1c2VyLmNvbQ== net::ERR_ABORTED 401
(anonymous) @ VM270:1
DOMEval @ jquery.js:82
domManip @ jquery.js:5782
    append @ jquery.js:5918
    (anonymous) @ plugin.js:80
```

BTW, "mein" is German for "my". I recall mein-bmi used to be a German site to calculate your body-mass index.

I use Windows here. I do not find mein-bmi in the registry and not in the Chrome settings. How can I find out why this is happening?

Comment: Check your browser addons. Disable all of them and check if this is still happening.

Comment: disabling all unknown apps and extensions worked

Comment: make this an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: That's more of a troubleshooting step than an answer. You could post your own answer if you can pinpoint a particular addon that does this.